# Trying to create new database via liquibase, postgresql, spring boot. Result-> "databasechangelog" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to create a new database-schema using liquibase (3.3), postgresql (9.4), and spring-boot. The relevant code and exception is pasted below.

I have created the empty test db on my local postgresql server.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-12-02 20:20:08.971 ERROR 3823 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:238)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.test.liquibase.repository.DatabaseChangeLogRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53249fb1.findDatabaseChangeLogs(<generated>)
    at com.test.liquibase.LiquibaseChangeLogReporter.onApplicationEvent(LiquibaseChangeLogReporter.java:49)
    at com.test.liquibase.LiquibaseChangeLogReporter.onApplicationEvent(LiquibaseChangeLogReporter.java:29)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.test.schema.dbInitializer.main(LearnSchemaInitializer.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.liquibase.repository.DatabaseChangeLogRepository.findDatabaseChangeLogs(DatabaseChangeLogRepository.java:38)
    at com.test.liquibase.repository.DatabaseChangeLogRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d54e8385.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" does not exist
  Position: 382
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

application.properties

```
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/liquibase/changelog.xml
liquibase.default-schema=test
liquibase.user=postgres
liquibase.password=postgres

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.host=localhost
spring.datasource.port=5432
spring.datasource.database=test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${spring.datasource.host}:${spring.datasource.port}/${spring.datasource.database}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

changelog.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

        <include file="data/initial_schema.liquibase.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

    </databaseChangeLog>

initial_schema.liquibase.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd ">

    <changeSet id="1.0" author="">

        <createTable tableName="TestTable">
            <column name="test1Id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="orgId" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="cartId" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

dbInitializer.java

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.test", "com.test.liquibase", "com.test.liquibase.repository" })
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.test.liquibase")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class dbInitializer
{
    private static final Logger LOG = dbInitializer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            SpringApplication.run(dbInitializer.class, args);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.error("Execution failed.", ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're running the liquibase base script, it is creating two additional tables to track the database updates by liquibase.

tables name

1. databasechangelog
2. databasechangeloglock

But you don't need to create these manually.It automatically creates when running liquibase script.

I think you have to run manually (commandline) liquibase script to create these tables and other table(only one time) after that incrementally updated database according to your liquibase scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: @alex17883 to say thx on stackoverflow is upvoting the answer (or even accepting it if it solves your problem).